# Grails - Many to one relation null id on .save()

Tags: hibernate, grails

I'm trying to insert two entries in my database (a User and a Photo), where Photo belongs to User, but when I save the user to the database I get the error

> Column 'user_id' cannot be null

Photo.groovy:

```
class Photo {

    Boolean active = 1
    Boolean approved = 0
    Date dateAdded = new Date()
    String filterName
    String senderIp
    String originalUrl
    String editedUrl
    User user

    static belongsTo = [User]
    static mapping = {
        active defaultValue: 1
        approved defaultValue: 0
        user column: 'user_id'
    }
    static constraints = {
        originalUrl maxSize: 512
        editedUrl maxSize: 512
        senderIp maxSize: 15
    }
}
```

User.groovy

```
class User {

    String address
    String number
    Date birthday
    String city
    String complement
    String cpf
    String guardianCpf
    String guardianName
    String email
    String firstName
    String lastName
    String mobile
    String neighborhood
    String phone
    String rg
    String sex
    String state
    String zipcode

    static hasMany = [photos: Photo]

    static constraints = {
        address maxSize: 256
        complement maxSize: 32
        city maxSize: 64
        complement nullable: true, maxSize: 32
        cpf maxSize: 11, unique: true
        guardianCpf maxSize: 11, nullable: true
        guardianName maxSize: 256, nullable: true
        email email: true, blank: false
        firstName maxSize: 128
        lastName maxSize: 128
        mobile maxSize: 12
        neighborhood maxSize: 128
        phone maxSize: 12
        rg maxSize: 9, unique: true
        sex maxSize: 1
        state maxSize: 2
        zipcode maxSize: 9
    }
}
```

UserService.groovy

```
@Transactional
class UserService {
    def grailsApplication
    def registerUser(String address, String number, Date birthday, String city, String complement,
            String cpf, String guardianCpf, String email, String firstName,
            String lastName, String mobile, String neighborhood, String phone,
            String rg, String sex, String state, String zipcode, String filterName, String originalUrl, String editedUrl, String senderIp) {
        def status = 0
        def content = ""
        def u = new User(
                address         : address,
                number          : number,
                birthday        : birthday,
                city            : city,
                complement      : complement,
                cpf             : cpf,
                email           : email,
                firstName       : firstName,
                lastName        : lastName,
                mobile          : mobile,
                neighborhood    : neighborhood,
                phone           : phone,
                rg              : rg,
                sex             : sex,
                state           : state,
                zipcode         : zipcode,
                guardianCpf     : guardianCpf)
        //I EDITED THIS PART OF THE CODE, TO SOLVE THE CODE SEE BELOW
        if (u.validate()){
            def p = new Photo(
                    filterName : filterName,
                    originalUrl : originalUrl,
                    editedUrl : editedUrl,
                    senderIp : senderIp,
                    user : u
                    )
            if (p.validate()){
                try{

                    u.addToPhotos(p).save(failOnError:true)
                    status = 1
                    content = "SUCCESS"
                }
                catch(e){
                    status = 0
                    content = grailsApplication.config.serviceErrors.databaseError
                }
            }
            else{
                status = 0
                content = grailsApplication.config.serviceErrors.invalidUserData + ": n"
                p.errors.allErrors.each {
                    content += it.toString() + "'"
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            status = 0
            content = grailsApplication.config.serviceErrors.invalidUserData + ": n"
            u.errors.allErrors.each {
                content += it.toString() + "'"
            }
        }
        return [status: status, content: content]
    }
}
```

Can someone help me?

EDIT:
Now I'm saving the user before adding the photo and now I get the error:

> null id in seviranaembalagem.User entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)

```
try{
    u.save(failOnError:true)
    u.addToPhotos(p)
    p.save(flush: true)
    status = 1
    content = "SUCCESS"
}
catch(e){
    status = 0
    content = grailsApplication.config.serviceErrors.databaseError
}
```

EDIT2 : 
Problem solved with this code at UserService.groovy:

```
if (u.validate()){
    u.save()
    def p = new Photo(
            filterName : filterName,
            originalUrl : originalUrl,
            editedUrl : editedUrl,
            senderIp : senderIp,
            user : u
            )
    if (p.validate()){
        try{                    
            p.save(flush:true)
            status = 1
            content = "SUCCESS"
        }
        catch(e){
            status = 0
            content = grailsApplication.config.serviceErrors.databaseError + e
        }
    }
    else{
        status = 0
        content = grailsApplication.config.serviceErrors.invalidUserData + ": n"
        p.errors.allErrors.each {
            content += it.toString() + "'"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to show the controller/service code you've written to do the save.

Comment: Done, thanks for remembering me

Comment: You have not saved the user yet before adding user to photo `(user : u)`.

Comment: I did as shown in my last edit and now I get the error: null id in seviranaembalagem.User entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)